# fazer pagamento no paypal sem obrigar o cliente a registar sem conta

Tags: php

Estou a usar a seguinte API para fazer o pagamento via paypal. http://www.webmaster.pt/formulario-recebimento-paypal-4281.html

O que me aparece quando vou fazer o pagamento é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, não quero obrigar o utilizador a criar conta no paypal. No ficheiro de configuração tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php
$paypal[business]="email@email.com";
$paypal[site_url]="http://link_site.com/";
$paypal[image_url]="";
$paypal[success_url]="php_paypal/success.php";
//$paypal[success_url]="php_paypal/ipn/ipn.php";
$paypal[cancel_url]="php_paypal/error.php";
$paypal[notify_url]="php_paypal/ipn/ipn.php";
$paypal[return_method]="1"; //1=GET 2=POST
$paypal[currency_code]="EUR"; //[USD,GBP,JPY,CAD,EUR]
$paypal[lc]="US";

$paypal[url]="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$paypal[post_method]="fso"; //fso=fsockopen(); curl=curl command line libCurl=php compiled with libCurl support
$paypal[curl_location]="/usr/local/bin/curl";

$paypal[bn]="toolkit-php";
$paypal[cmd]="_xclick";

//Payment Page Settings
$paypal[display_comment]="0"; //0=yes 1=no
$paypal[comment_header]="Comments";
$paypal[continue_button_text]="Continue >>";
$paypal[background_color]=""; //""=white 1=black
$paypal[display_shipping_address]=""; //""=yes 1=no
$paypal[display_comment]="1"; //""=yes 1=no


//Product Settings
$paypal[item_name]="$_POST[item_name]";
$paypal[item_number]="$_POST[item_number]";
$paypal[amount]="$_POST[amount]";
$paypal[on0]="$_POST[on0]";
$paypal[os0]="$_POST[os0]";
$paypal[on1]="$_POST[on1]";
$paypal[os1]="$_POST[os1]";
$paypal[quantity]="$_POST[quantity]";
$paypal[edit_quantity]=""; //1=yes ""=no
$paypal[invoice]="$_POST[invoice]";
$paypal[tax]="$_POST[tax]";

//Shipping and Taxes
$paypal[shipping_amount]="$_POST[shipping_amount]";
$paypal[shipping_amount_per_item]="";
$paypal[handling_amount]="";
$paypal[custom_field]="";

//Customer Settings
$paypal[firstname]="$_POST[firstname]";
$paypal[lastname]="$_POST[lastname]";
$paypal[address1]="$_POST[address1]";
$paypal[address2]="$_POST[address2]";
$paypal[city]="$_POST[city]";
$paypal[state]="$_POST[state]";
$paypal[zip]="$_POST[zip]";
$paypal[email]="$_POST[email]";
$paypal[phone_1]="$_POST[phone1]";
$paypal[phone_2]="$_POST[phone2]";
$paypal[phone_3]="$_POST[phone3]";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com as informações no [site do paypal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside) isso é automático, você tem a opção de desativar este recurso na sua conta do paypal que recebe os pagamentos e não na integração dele com o seu programa, porém este recurso só está disponível se a sua conta for Premier ou Business

Existe também a possibilidade deste recurso não estar disponível em todos os países, mas não encontrei informações sobre isso então não posso dizer isso com certeza, só entrando em contato com eles para ter certeza disso.

Comment: Não consigo encontrar a opção nas configurações. Sabe qual o caminho? No meu caso não uso checkout transparente, uso checkout simples.